# PHP preg_replace Calculation Not working

Tags: php

I am trying to create a hook, so that when the following is found within text:

```
level,2
```

It replaces it with `$skill_level * $n`, with the number after the comma being `$n`

Here is what I have:

```
$skill_level = 2;

$row['s_effect'] = "Long string of text that contains level,2."

preg_replace("/level,$n/",$skill_level * $n,$row['s_effect'])
```

I am getting a result of:

```
Long string of text that contains 02.
```

I want a result of:

```
Long string of text that contains 4.
```

For some reason it seems the calculation `"$skill_level * $n" (2 * 2)` is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `preg_replace_callback`

```
$skill_level = 2;
$text = "Long string of text that contains level,2.";

$ret = preg_replace_callback("/level,(\d+)/", function ($matches) use ($skill_level) {
  return $matches[1] * $skill_level;
}, $text);
```

Comment: Just out of interest, is there are particular reason why you're using a look-behind assertion instead of just using a memory group?

Comment: This is close I think I am getting:

Long string of text that contains level,4.

Should be: Long string of text that contains 4.

Comment: To make this solution work, when calling $ret I used preg_replace("/level,/","",$ret)

Comment: @user1625155 I miss read your question, thought you only want to replace the number. Updated my answer.